# Use belongsTo and hasMany in a Controller [CakePHP]

Tags: cakephp, controller, url-rewriting, categories

Im a beginner with CakePHP,

i wonder how i do this in my controller's action :

```
$this->Image->Category->findAllByRewrite($category_rewrite);
```

i want to get all the images of the category ..

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be 100% sure what you are asking, but if you are adding this in the ImagesController you are on the right track. I do not think you need to chain the Category model as you are indicating though.

You would do something like:

```
$category_id = $value;

$images = $this->Image->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Image.category_id' => $category_id)));
```

With more clarification I can change this response.